# It is possible to make a Clearcase config spec pointing to different branches?

Tags: clearcase

We are trying set up a complex project and we are trying to limit the number of views and branches.
We are working in UCM ClearCase where different groups work independently then merge into a merge branch once everything clears testing.

Is it at all possible to point the config spec of our new views to several different branches?
If so is there anything that we need to think about?
Maybe someone could post an example that they have created?

Comment: What exact problem are you trying to solve? I will edit my answer to explain how to solve it with ClearCase (without resorting to a "view pointing to different branches")

Answer (score 1):

An UCM view is always related to *one* Stream, so using *one* branch (if said Stream contains modifiable components)

A base ClearCase view could be configured to monitor several branches, but only one rule (the last one which can be applied for a given file version) will prevail, ie only one branch will be selected.

So it isn't possible.